# ¿como solucionar un error al compilar una aplicacion cordova con el visual estudio?

Tags: android

el error que me sale es el siguiente

alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

> Error code 1 for command: cmd with args:
>   /s,/c,"C:\Users\Egarcia\Desktop\MOZREPO-06-\MOZREPO-06-03-2018-no-plugin\MOZREPO-06-03-2018\MOZREPO\MOZmovil\platforms\android\gradlew
>   cdvBuildRelease -b
>   C:\Users\Egarcia\Desktop\MOZREPO-06-\MOZREPO-06-03-2018-no-plugin\MOZREPO-06-03-2018\MOZREPO\MOZmovil\platforms\android\build.gradle
>   -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true"

Comment: can any one help me r_r

Comment: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Roberto\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1 MOZmovil  1 Compilación